# Pop view controller to a common view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've a Dashboard like app and at some point I would like to pop back to the "Dashboard" view controller. I cannot change the root view controller. The way I accomplished this task is by a static instance. I use this code:

```
static DashboardViewController *instance;
+ (instancetype) instance {
  return instance;
}
```

This instance is set in the viewDidLoad to self.

So then when I want to pop to this controller I use:

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[DashboardViewController instance] animated:YES];
```

What I like to know if this is the way to go or should this be different?

Comment: If the dashboard viewcontroller (VC) is in the stack, then it's fine. It seems from your wording that Dashboard VC is not the root VC. However, if it *is* the root VC, you can use [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] instead.

Comment: This method ok if you use one instance of this viewcontroller.If there is multiple instance can be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (UIViewController  *viewController in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {

    //you can also use NSClassFromString(@"DashboardViewController") instead of [DashboardViewController class]
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[DashboardViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very remote. When It loops through the loop completely without result I will instantiate on and pop to it thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[DashboardViewController class]])
    {
        //Do not forget to import DashboardViewController.h

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```